# Why doesn't the full directory name display when passing an exclude parameter which passes it to a for loop to display?

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.1

So, I actually don't believe that its the string value I'm passing to the parameter that is the issue, I think its how my `for` loop is displaying it.

```
Function Get-Users{
[cmdletbinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,
                   ValueFromPipeLine=$true,
                   ValueFromPipeLineByPropertyName=$true,
                   HelpMessage='Enter Computer Name')]
                   [Alias('CN','Computer','Name')]
                   [ValidateLength(1,15)]
                   [string]$ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,
                   ValueFromPipeLine=$true,
                   ValueFromPipeLineByPropertyName=$true)]
                   [String]$Exclude

                   )

$UNC = Get-ChildItem -Path \\$ComputerName\c$\Users -Exclude $Exclude -Directory | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name | Sort-Object -Descending
    for($i=0; $i -lt $UNC.Count; $i++){
        "$($i): $($UNC[$i])" }

      ""
$SS = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter # of user(s)"
$s  = $SS -split " "
    foreach($user in $UNC[$s]){
        "$User" }

}
```

I feel like this should work as it does when I do it when just running it in the console like so: `Get-ChildItem -Path C:\users -Exclude "Abraham" -Directory`; It simply excludes my directory listing.

Even when nothing is specified in the parameter it still runs just fine: `Get-ChildItem -Path C:\users -Exclude "" -Directory` in regards to listing all directories, but when I pass it using my self-made parameters it doesn't display correctly. What I get instead is the following:

```
PS > Get-Users -Exclude Abraham

0: P

Enter # of user(s):
```

When it should be:

```
PS > Get-Users -Exclude Abraham

0: Public

Enter # of user(s):
```

Can someone educate me on why it doesn't display the full Directory name?

Please note that itll list all directories when the `-Exclude` Parameter isn't specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this `$UNC = Get-ChildItem -Path \\$C......` for this `$UNC = @(Get-ChildItem -Path \\$C......)` or this `[array]$UNC = Get-ChildItem -Path \\$C.......`

The problem is that you're getting just one result from `gci`, because of that the variable is a string and not an array, hence when calling the position 0 of your string you're getting the first letter of the string and not the first element of your array :)

```
PS /~> $unc=(gci *.txt).Name              
PS /~> for($i=0; $i -lt $unc.count; $i++)
{
    "$($i): $($UNC[$i])" 
}
0: t
PS /~> [array]$unc=$unc
PS /~> for($i=0; $i -lt $unc.count; $i++)
{
    "$($i): $($UNC[$i])" 
}
0: test.txt
```

Comment: That's funny cause that's the first thing I tried. Maybe it was due to it being still loaded into memory that it didn't work when i casted it as an array? Either ways, I'm sure it works but, Im not in front of my computer so I'll mark it as the answer anyways! Thanks for the clarification!